# I want to run next work when several works are done which are running at same time

Tags: c#

I want to run next work when several works are done which are running at same time

I can't expect the order in which work are done.

```
WorkA, WorkB, WorkC is running at the same time at different threads
```

when each work is done
the `code Manager.SetWorkState(Manager.WorkState)` is run

```
Ex : WorkA is done
Manager.SetWorkState(Manager.WorkState) Manager.SetWorkState(Manager.WorkState.WorkAIsDone); 

class Manager
{

    public enum WorkState
    {
        WorkAIsDone = 0x1,
        WorkBIsDone = 0x2,
        WorkCIsDone = 0x4,
    }

        WorkState state;

    public void SetWorkState(WorkState newState)
    {
        state = state | newState;
        if (state == (WorkState.WorkAIsDone | WorkState.WorkBIsDone | WorkState.WorkCIsDone))
        {
            Run_NextWork();
        }
    }

    public void Run_NextWork() { ... }
}
```

Is there more efficent solution for this case?

What is your solution for this case?

Comment: So you want something to happen when A, B and C have finished?

Comment: It is *not* inefficient, takes but a few nanoseconds.  Focus on writing *correct* code instead, `state = newState | newState;` is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks That is fixed

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. First, if the "work" can be completed asynchronously, then you have a thread-safety problem, as two threads could be calling `SetWorkState()` at the same time, resulting in a flag bit failing to be set. Also, it is not clear how the work is being performed. You say each "work" item is in a different thread, but how do you accomplish this. The one answer suggested so far seems useful...if you think it's not, you need to explain how you have "work" running in individual threads, but no apparent way to identify their completion.

Comment: thanks for answer.
thread-safety problem exists.
I have to fix this with lock.
and the work is request and response.
Worker just sending a request to server.
an event occur when response is received.
after processing response, the work is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy solution to this, using the [Task Parellel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). 
Following is just some `pseudocode` but i hope you get the idea

```
class Manager
{
    List<Task> _tasks;

    public Manager()
    {

        _tasks = new List<Task>();

        //assuming your 3 tasks are already started from somewhere, run fourth task 
        StartNewTask(Run_NextWork);
    }

    public void StartNewTask(Action action)
    {
        //WaitAll waits for all tasks in array to complete before continuing
        Task.WaitAll(_tasks.ToArray());
        var newTask = Task.Run(action);
    }

    public void Run_NextWork()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
But each work includes waiting repsonse message from server.
It is not just running 1 method.